# Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6 pull-right equivalent

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've updated from Alpha 4 to Alpha 6, and I can't for the life of me get what was `pull-right` to work on a span. I know `pull-right` has been removed, but I can't seem to get anything to work, i.e. `float-*-right`, etc.

What I used to have was:

```
   <li>
      <a href = "#">
         <span class = "badge pull-right">3</span>
         Messages
      </a>
   </li>
```

Which gave the effect of:

[image]

Can someone please advise me how to get this same right alignment on the span in Alpha 6, it's starting to crack me up...

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle ? I will find quickly

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've found the solution, I'll answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad, it's right there in the docs, you have to add `justify-content-between` to the `li` class.

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item justify-content-between">
    Cras justo odio
    <span class="badge badge-default badge-pill">14</span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item justify-content-between">
    Dapibus ac facilisis in
    <span class="badge badge-default badge-pill">2</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The pull-left and pull-right classes have been replaced by:

```
.float-{xs,sm,md,lg,xl}-{left,right,none}
```

So that's

```
.float-right
.float-sm-right
```

for example.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but as I said, that doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry I missed that syntax in your post